# Reading all string from a server socket which has not been closed

Tags: java, python, sockets, readline

I have a problem with socket programming in Java. 
There is a server which has been written in python like this which I shouldn't not change.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send('from server\nnewline\0')
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
```

Now I want to write a code in Java which read the string from a server. Something like this:

```
public static String readStr(Socket client) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(
                client.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader inBuff = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String answer = new String();
        String str = inBuff.readLine();
        while (str!=null) {
            answer = answer.concat(str + "\n");
            str = inBuff.readLine();
        }
        answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1);
        System.out.println("answer:\n "+answer);
        return answer;
    }
```

But it seems that it blocks at line `str = inBuff.readLine();` at the last line of the message. I tried the `read()` method but it was blocked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing a protocol over tcp, the best way is to include some kind of framer. This is done in the current protocol by the usage of a <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte.

When reading the data from the socket, you should first divide it into blocks/frames by some operations, before parsing the individual blocks.

A crude way to divide the packets into blocks is reading until you find a <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte, then returning that block as a byte array. *(This is not the most efficient implementation)*

```
public byte[] readPacket(InputStream in) throws IOException {
     ByteArrayOutputStream tempStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     int read;
     read=in.read();
     while(read > 0){
       tempStr.write(read);
       read=in.read();
       }
     if(read == -1)
         throw new EOFException();
     return tempStr.toByteArray();
}
```

Because you now have proper frames for your data, you can now easily read the data:

```
byte[] frame = readPacket(in);
String[] lines = new String(frame, StandardCharsets.UTF8).split("\n");
// Do something with the lines
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the last line sent by the server does not end and readLine() method only returns when it reaches end of the line. Since you change the server's code. I recommend you use another method for reading from the stream. You may also use InputStreamReader class.

Comment: I have used nputStreamReader class. which other method you recommend?
@user6015630

Comment: You could use read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) in BufferedReader

Answer (score 0):

Apart from already mentioned inconsistent message/line ending - once with `\n`, second with `\0`, at the server there is no detection of end of the message. So the server will loop as long as the socket is not closed (or shut down for writing) at the client side. And as you have this line before closing the socket:

```
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

in other words the client is waiting for some response from the server. But the server is stuck forever reading the message from the client in a loop.

So you need to either close the socket prior to that `recv` call or send some message (like empty line) and detect in on the server and eventually exit the loop.